More accurate translation of どうするかみてろ
I’m trying to translate some dialogue including the line どうするかみてろ, and I’m wondering if it’d be more accurate to translate that phrase as something like “watch what I will do” versus “watch what I can do”. Is one more than the other, between “will” and “can”, particularly suggested from that sort of phrasing?

Without further context, it's hard to say.  To me this sounds like it could mean something like "Let's see what we do" or "Let's see what what they do" or something similar.  If you provide some context in which this was said, we will be better able to help you.

The original text obviously doesn't contain any potential form. Is anything wrong with "See what I'll do" in the context? Adding a small word such as "can" to make the text more readable is basically up to the translator's discretion, but if you present this out of context, all I can say is "There is no potential form".

@A.Ellett The context had the speaker addressing an opponent, and seemingly about to show off to them or actively retaliate against them in some way; that distinction probably encompasses the difference between that connotations of “can do” versus “will do”, since the former seems to focus on the speaker sort of one-upping a rival by showing off some potential ability, while the latter more directly suggests the character actually planning to use that ability. Then again I suppose both readings of the line’s connotations can apply to such a short phrase even in its English version(s)?

I agree with @naruto that there is no potential form here.  So, as a translator you may choose to go with "can do", but you're adding a nuance in English that isn't present in the Japanese.

I think it would be useful to have more context.  But grammatically, どうするかみてろ can still be analyzed.
みてろ is 命令形 command-form of みている.
This means, "[wait and] see."  "wait" is perhaps a bit of a stretch for the meaning of いる.  More literally, "be and see".  But "wait and see" is more colloquial English.
Without context, it's hard to say what どうするか is actually expressing.  する makes clear someone is going to be doing something.  Context might make clear who this someone is.  Broadly speaking it's likely either

Wait and see what we're going to do.

or

Wait and see what they're going to do.


みてろ is not volitional, but imperative. Volitional would be みて（い）よう.

@Axe Ah yes.  Corrected.  Not sure what I was thinking there.
